# Can the 2011 Mac Mini support 3 displays with DP 1.2 chaining?

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, displayport, daisy-chaining

Dell u2713H monitor supports Daisy Chaining. as one of the first monitors I've seen that uses DP 1.2 protocol. In essence, I'm asking if thunderbolt supports / enables / works with DP chaining, but the practical question is more obvious.

Can I connect 3 of those monitors to my 2011 Intel HD Mac Mini via it's one Thunderbolt port?

Comment: I thought that thunderbolt supports only data chains, not display ones...

Comment: From wikipedia: Thunderbolt combines PCI Express (PCIe) and DisplayPort (DP) into one serial signal. DP 1.2 supports monitor Daisy Chaining. But maybe i am overlooking something?

Comment: yep, found some info on chaining http://www.macrumors.com/2011/09/16/apple-thunderbolt-display-with-multiple-monitors/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thunderbolt -> Triple Monitor Mac Mini?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17977/thunderbolt-triple-monitor-mac-mini)

Comment: I am 100% this is NOT possible with any "normal" monitor. This is not possible with Thunderbolt Display also. My Mac Mini can only support 2 displays max and only one of them can have 2560x1440 resolution. But Dell u2713h is one of the first monitors with DP 1.2 and Daisy Chaining. @Mark: not duplicate because DP 1.2 is something pretty new on monitors.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but DP 2.1 doesn't exist, it's DP 1.2.