# Can a Non-Thunderbolt device (like a mid 2010 iMac) connect to a Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I've been browsing different forums for this answer and the closest answer I could find was [a post on this Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17960/are-there-adapters-to-use-thunderbolt-display-with-non-thunderbolt-computers).

However this post is still a 'may be' it won't work and it targets the general question 'Non Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt ?' which I would understand to be negative.

My question is more on the display side, since the thunderbolt technology [carries both a display signal as well a pci express signal](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/02/thunderbolt-smokes-usb-firewire-with-10gbps-throughput.ars), can a non-thunderbolt diplay with a simple display port still carry that signal to a thunderbolt cinema display ?

Thanks for your knowledge on that matter.

Comment: System Requirements
 Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac
    OS X v10.6.8 or later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot. That's the reason Apple is still selling the non-thunderbolt 27" display, for the devices like yours.

Source: Apple Online Store, where under system requirements it says:

System Requirements

Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac

Comment: plain and simple thanks. Those displays are unfortunately getting scarce so people in the same situation will have to decide soon.

Comment: Yes. I think it's an unfortunate decision for Apple because, will you decide to buy, say, a MBA, you will not be able to get all those additional ports. Of course the display will work, and you'll just have to buy one of those hopefully-out-soon Thunderbolt hub (gosh how much I want them) in that case, but still, Apple could have saved a lot of overhead to its supply chain and its customer.

Comment: I've found something quite interesting. There is a company doing multi monitor signal splitting from one video input, [Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/?productTabs=1#specs) and they recently added a [Thunderbolt compatible device](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/press/releases/2011/dualhead2go_dp/triplehead2go_dp/macbook_pro_thunderbolt/) acting as a Thunderbolt hub. Looks amazing...

Answer (score 5):

You will find the requirements on the [Apple](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) website

> System Requirements Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including
>   MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac OS X v10.6.8 or later

There is a [good article here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/09/18/thunderbolt-display-daisy-chaining-spec-cleared-up/) on the connectivity of the Thunderbolt displays that may help you understand