# How do I connect my PC to a Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: thunderbolt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there adapters to use Thunderbolt Display with non-Thunderbolt computers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17960/are-there-adapters-to-use-thunderbolt-display-with-non-thunderbolt-computers)

So, I have a MacBook Air and a 27" Thunderbolt display. I was under the impression that I could connect my PC (Asus Laptop) to the Thunderbolt display by using a HDMI to Mini Displayport converter. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Is there some technical limitation as to why this isn't working?

Comment: What video out and other ports does your Asus include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but currently it's not possible. Thunderbolt ports on Macs can output a Mini Displayport signal, but the Thunderbolt *Display* can only receive a Thunderbolt signal, nothing else. It's possible that an adapter to do this could be released in the future, but IMO that's unlikely or if it happens will be quite expensive.