# Can I use a Thunderbolt display for a macbook pro with a mini display port?

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt-display

I have an older macbook pro with a mini display port. Can I use a Thunderbolt display as an external monitor?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17960/ ...*you can only connect Thunderbolt equipped computers into the Thunderbolt display.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Thunderbolt displays will only work with a Thunderbolt port on your machine - not with a Mini Display Port...