# Daisy chain Dell with DisplayPort (output) to Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display, cinema-display, daisy-chaining

I have a Dell P2720DC and Apple Thunderbolt Displays I want to daisy chain. Since the Dell has USB-C PD, I prefer connecting my MacBook to it, but then I'm not sure I can connect its DisplayPort output to Apple Thunderbolt Display.

Would it work? Which cable/adaptor to use?

If not, are there other options?

Comment: You can't.  The Apple display is a data connection over Thunderbolt, the Dell monitor is DisplayPort over USBC.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won’t work in a daisy chain situation.

- [Are there adapters to use Thunderbolt Display with non-Thunderbolt computers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17960/are-there-adapters-to-use-thunderbolt-display-with-non-thunderbolt-computers)

How many Thunderbolt ports does your MacBook have?

Perhaps a Thunderbolt dock is what you need? The ones from caldigit are superb and give a lot of value for the price.